# Array de objetos em JAVA

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Fala galera beleza ?
Então, sou iniciante em desenvolvimento java e minha primeiro dúvida cruel que bati de frente em uma questão no curso foi a seguinte.

"Faça o cadastro dos dados de uma conta corrente ou uma conta poupança. Peça ao usuário para digitar cada informação solicitada. Apos inserir os dados, imprima o valor de cada atributo da classe instanciada.

Crie também os métodos Sacar, Depositar, Imprimir dados, Aplicar Rendimento.

Atributos:

Conta Corrente tem: Agencia, Nr_conta, Saldo, Nome do Titular, Limite;

Poupança: Agencia, Nr_conta, Saldo, Nome do Titular,rendimento;

Crie uma classe Principal com Void Main(),

Faça um menu para:

Menu

1 - Cadastrar Conta Corrente

2 - Cadastrar Poupança

3 - Saque de Conta Corrente

4 - Saque de Poupança

5 - Depósito em Conta Corrente

6 - Depósito em Poupança

7 - Saldo de Conta Corrente

8 - Saldo de Poupança

9 - Aplicação de Rendimentos na Poupança

10- para sair

Faça o diagrama de classe e o programa.

Deixe os atributos das classes como private, crie os metodos gets e sets.

Faça os demais métodos, conforme o menu."

Até ai tudo bem, fiz tudo corretamente, e o prof já corrigiu, depois ele me pediu o seguinte.

"Faça a questão acima e armazene cada objeto em um vetor.

Dica: como temos um vetor que é um conjunto de objetos, antes de realizar qualquer operação você deverá localizar, para assim realizar a tarefa. Crie também uma variável para controlar o índice, do último objeto armazenado.

Faça também o método informar a quantidade de conta corrente ou poupança cadastrados.

Limite o vetor a 20 posição para cada tipo de objeto."
package aula_21desafio;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programa {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    int opt;

    ContaCorrente[] cc = new ContaCorrente[20];
    ContaPoupança[] cp = new ContaPoupança[20];

    do {

        System.out.println("\tMenu\n");
        System.out.println("Escolha abaixo qual opção desejada:\n");
        System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Conta Corrente");
        System.out.println("2 - Cadastrar Conta Poupança");
        System.out.println("3 - Sacar Conta Poupança");
        System.out.println("4 - Sacar Conta Corrente");
        System.out.println("5 - Depósito Conta Poupança");
        System.out.println("6 - Depósito Conta Corrente");
        System.out.println("7 - Saldo Conta Poupança");
        System.out.println("8 - Saldo Conta Corrente");
        System.out.println("9 - Aplicação de Rendimentos na Poupança");
        System.out.println("10 - Sair");
        System.out.print("Opção: ");

        opt = Integer.parseInt(read.nextLine());

        switch (opt) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Você escolheu conta corrente");

            System.out.println("Qual o seu nome? ");
            String nomeDoTitular = read.nextLine().trim();

            System.out.println("Digite o número da agência: ");
            String agencia = read.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Digite o número da conta: ");
            String numeroDaConta = read.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Qual o limite desejado? ");
            double limite = Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine().replace(",", "."));

            System.out.println("Digite um valor inicial a ser depositado: ");
            double saldo = Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine().replace(",", "."));

            for(int i =0;i<=cc.length;i++) {
            cc[i]= new ContaCorrente(nomeDoTitular, agencia, numeroDaConta, limite, saldo);         
            cc[i].exibirInfos();
            break;
            }
            break;
```

Quando tento acessar qualquer indice diferente do 0, recebo NullPointerException, porque ele nao salva cada conta em cada indice ?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem um `break;` dentro do loop, isso faz com que o loop seja interrompido na primeira iteração e seja adicionado apenas `cc[0]`, retire essa quebra para adicionar a todos os índices do array

Mas por que preencher um array com os mesmos dados? Não faria mais sentido adicionar apenas um e, quando o usuário solicitar, adicionar outro

Observaçao: o padrão de nomenclatura do Java não usa acentos, ou seja, em vez de `ContaPoupança` coloque `ContaPoupanca`

Comment: Exatamente essa era minha dúvida, tirando o break, ele cria uma conta igual em todos os indices. Valeu pela dica da "ContaPoupanca" !

Comment: Não lembro muito do Java, faz tempo que não uso. Mas acho que você precisa de um ArrayList, que tem o método `add` para adicionar itens, de uma estudada em arrays

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que seu for esteja adicionando cc apenas na posição 0 por causa do break dentro. Porem se tirar o break serão criadas várias contas iguais no array.